# phonegap/cordova run issue

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5

I have recently installed the newest version of Cordova (phonegap) 3.4.1 on my iMac. Downloaded the helloworld app. Built it according to the documentation in the platform guides at the command line. Opened xcode (5.1.1) and opened the helloword.xcodeproj file. I see all the files that I expect under WWW directory. Selected a simulator and clicked the Build button. I get the message that build succeeded.

And that's it. I can't seem to run it.

command-R is grayed out. I can't find any configuration that allows Build and Run.

When I did native iOS app development a couple of years ago using XCode 4.x I had the option of build or build/run. I don't see that similar information now.

Basically I just want to see the freaking program run in the simulator and my friend Google is letting me down.

Comment: Make sure you've selected the proper target in Xcode (right next to the play/stop buttons).

Comment: @KerriShotts Yeah, I did that. A little while ago I figured out that it was defaulting to cordova.lib as the scheme. I changed the scheme to helloworld and it worked.